# How can I check if a Perl module (DBD::mysql) is properly installed?

Tags: mysql, perl, xampp, dbi, dbd

I am using XAMPP on Mac OS X Yosemite, and I am trying to communicate with my MySQL database using Perl.

This requires two things: (1) DBI and (2) the mysql driver module, DBD::mysql.

I ran into a lot of trouble installing the DBD::mysql portion. However, after following some instructions online, it now *looks like* DBD::mysql is installed, but I am skeptical that it has correctly.

In **Terminal**, when I load up **cpan** and then type "install DBD::mysql", it responds, "DBD::mysql is up to date (4.032)".

From the looks of it, then, it is installed. However, I am worried that what I've installed is enough for it to say, "Hey, I am installed!", but not enough for it to actually be functional, which would be why I'm having errors show up when I try to connect to my database with Perl:

```
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 1): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib

Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
  Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 194.
 at (eval 6) line 3.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 6) line 3.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
 at login.pl line 9.
```

Relevant Perl code snippet:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(          
    "dbi:mysql:dbname=TEST", 
    "root",                          
    "",                          
    { RaiseError => 1 },         
) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

I am trying to troubleshoot whether this is a problem with my installation of DBD::mysql, or if it is my Perl code.

How can I verify whether my installation of DBD::mysql is all good? Better yet, how can I stop getting this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `connect()` call into an `eval` block to catch this error, however you don't have many options left if it crashes, probably just to try and produce a more user-friendly error messsage and then die anyway.

As for why you are getting the error, try checking where `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` lives on your system. It seems like it was somewhere where it could be found during compilation of the `DBD::mysql` driver but not during your script's runtime. Assuming it hasn't been accidentially uninstalled, adding its directory to the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable should work. I don't know what config to add the path to to make that addition permanent on OSX though.